# Javascript calculator issue

Tags: javascript, forms, calculator

I have a problem with a script and I don't know how to handle it.
I'm trying to make a simple calculator that displays how much you must pay for a  random model. I'm trying to display a different answer depending upon the amount of time and advance chosen in the select menu. The formulas in each if statement does actually work when I simply list the variables outside of if statements displaying each answer in a series of alert boxes, but I'd like to display only the applicable answer.What I am doing wrong?
Escuse my rudimentary JS skills butt I am still a beginner in this domain.Thanks for your time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Calculator</title>


<script script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function  rata() {
    var selection1 = document.getElementsById("model")[0].value;;
    var selection2 = document.getElementsById("time")[1].value;;
    var selection3 = document.getElementsById("advance")[2].value;;

    if(selection2 === "t1" && selection3 === "a1"){
        var pay1 = "100 euro";
        alert("You must pay"  +  pay1  +  ".");
    }
    else if(selection2 === "t1" && selection3 === "a2"){
        var pay2 = "200 euro";
        alert("You must pay"  +  pay2  +  ".");
    }
    else if(selection2 === "t2" && selection3 === "a1"){
        var pay3 = "400 euro";
        alert("You must pay"  +  rata3  +  ".");
    }
    else if(selection2 === "t2" && selection3 === "a2"){
        var pay4 = "800 euro";
        alert("You must pay"  +  pay4  +  ".");
    }
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

                    <form name="calculator">
                        Model <br><select name="model" id="model"> 
                                        <option value="">selectati modelul</option>
                                        <option value="model">Model 1</option>
                                        <option value="model">Model 2</option>
                                        <option value="model">Model 3</option>
                                        <option value="model">Model 4</option>
                                        <option value="model">Model 5</option>
                                        <option value="model">Model 6</option>
                                        <option value="model">Model 7</option>
                                        <option value="model">Model 8</option>
                                  </select><br>
                        Time <br><select name="time" id="time">
                                        <option value="">select time</option>
                                        <option value="t1">1 year</option>
                                        <option value="t2">2 years</option>
                                  </select> <br>
                        Advance <br><select name="advance" id="advance">
                                        <option value="" >select advance</option>
                                        <option value="a1" >0%</option>
                                        <option value="a2" >50%</option>
                                  </select> <br>
                                  <input type="button" value="Send" onclick="pay()">
                    </form> 


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't understand what you need to do. Whatever it is sound simple so send me a mail in romanian (you are romanian by name) to elzozo13@yahoo.com and maybe I can understand it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input type="button" value="Send" onclick="pay()">` <--- this calls "pay()", but your function is called "rata()"

`document.getElementsById("model")[0].value;` <-- there is no such function, it's not plural, it should be: `getElementById`

`document.getElementById("model")[0].value;` will never give you the value of a SELECT. Use this:

```
var sel1 = document.getElementById("model")
var val1 = sel1[sel1.selectedIndex].value
```

Since you're getting the value, and all of the values are "model" you will get the same value regardless of what the user chooses.

Comment: thanks a lot,that work's great.But if i want the final result to appear below "send" button and not like an alert what I must do?

Comment: Make a div and write into it: document.getElementsById("results").innerHTML = "you have results!"